# Compile Linux V4L-DVB media_build for a specific kernel (not the running one)

Tags: linux, kernel, v4l2

Is it possible to compile the [LinuxTV.org V4L-DVB media_build](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers) for a kernel source contained in a specific path, instead of the running one (i.e. a different version)?

I have the **kernel sources** and in **/root/mytest/linux-3.12.6** (vanilla) and the kernel config in **/root/mytest/linux-3.12.6/.config** but I'm not able to find a way to tell the **./build** script it's there.

For example:

```
# make tar DIR=/root/mytest/linux-3.12.6
```

fails because it cannot finds some files:

```
tar: mm/frame_vector.c: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/linux/fence.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/linux/of_graph.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/linux/dma/xilinx_dma.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/trace/events/v4l2.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/trace/events/vb2.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/uapi/linux/lirc.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/uapi/linux/media-bus-format.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/uapi/linux/vsp1.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/uapi/linux/xilinx-v4l2-controls.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: include/uapi/linux/smiapp.h: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
make: *** [tar] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple but not so well "published"; I've found it on a discussion available [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.video-input-infrastructure/97397).
Basically, first you have to build the kernel in its own path (with `make allmodconfig` and `make init`) and then, in **media_build**, you run:

```
# make release DIR=/root/mytest/linux-3.12.6

make -C /root/mytest/media_build/v4l release
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/mtest/media_build/v4l'
Searching in /root/mytest/linux-3.12.6/Makefile for kernel version.
Forcing compiling to version 3.12.6
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/mytest/media_build/v4l'

# ./build
```

As you can see it picks up the correct kernel version from the path you've specified with the **DIR** switch.